# Why can't cocoapods install zxingobjc

Tags: ios, barcode, zxing, cocoapods

in my project Podfile, it contains this line - pod 'ZXingObjC', '~> 2.2.6'
then I execute this command: pod install --verbose --no-repo-update

> Analyzing dependencies
>
> Finding Podfile changes
>     A ZXingObjC
>
> Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
>   Resolving dependencies for target `Pods' (iOS 5.0)
>     - ZXingObjC (~> 2.2.6)
>
> Comparing resolved specification to the sandbox manifest
>     A ZXingObjC
>
> Downloading dependencies
>
> -> Installing ZXingObjC (2.2.6)
>
> > GitHub download
> >     Creating cache git repo (/Users/leo/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/GitHub/460c72131c6f29c2d0f283a2dc9a9d7c7ff3388f)
> >     Cloning to Pods folder
> >            $ /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC.git /Users/leo/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/GitHub/460c72131c6f29c2d0f283a2dc9a9d7c7ff3388f --mirror
> >            Cloning into bare repository '/Users/leo/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/GitHub/460c72131c6f29c2d0f283a2dc9a9d7c7ff3388f'...

It hangs here for a long time, and finally give below error:

> ```
>   error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
>   fatal: early EOF
>   fatal: index-pack failed
> ```

Any one knows how to solve this? I want to use ZXingObjc in my project...ios